# How __promisify__ in fs.d.ts works in design-time?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I found something interesting in fs.d.ts:

```js
declare module 'fs' {
    /**
     * Asynchronous rename(2) - Change the name or location of a file or directory.
     * @param oldPath A path to a file. If a URL is provided, it must use the `file:` protocol.
     * @param newPath A path to a file. If a URL is provided, it must use the `file:` protocol.
     */
    export function rename(oldPath: PathLike, newPath: PathLike, callback: NoParamCallback): void;

    // NOTE: This namespace provides design-time support for util.promisify. Exported members do not exist at runtime.
    export namespace rename {
        /**
         * Asynchronous rename(2) - Change the name or location of a file or directory.
         * @param oldPath A path to a file. If a URL is provided, it must use the `file:` protocol.
         * URL support is _experimental_.
         * @param newPath A path to a file. If a URL is provided, it must use the `file:` protocol.
         * URL support is _experimental_.
         */
        function __promisify__(oldPath: PathLike, newPath: PathLike): Promise<void>;
    }
}
```

As the NOTE said, `rename.__promisify__` is for design-time purpose.
I wonder how that works? Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [type overloads](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c886d9bf6be8a64bf7cde242779f8931b9ae329e/types/node/v14/util.d.ts#L86-L96) for `util.promisify` you can notice how `__promisify__` virtual property is used there to infer the type of the result function. The relevant to the question part is:

```ts
// -- util.d.ts
interface CustomPromisifyLegacy<TCustom extends Function> extends Function {
    __promisify__: TCustom;
}

declare function promisify<TCustom extends Function>(fn: CustomPromisifyLegacy<TCustom>): TCustom; // simplified

// -- testing type inference
declare function fn(a: string, cb: (result: string) => void): void
declare namespace fn {
    function __promisify__(a: string): Promise<string>
}

const promisified = promisify(fn) // ~ (a: string) => Promise<string>
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgr4yW)

I have simplified types a bit to illustrate the relevant type transformation logic.